# fluent nhibernate - many-to-many relationship mapping on same entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I am having a problem trying to map out a many-to-many relationship , where both sides of the relationship reference the same entity. I am using Fluent NHibernate and NH3.1.

Basically, the scenario is this - I have a category, which can have multiple parents. Thus, a category has multiple other categories as parents, as well as multiple other categories as its children.

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ParentCategories).AsBag().Table("parentcategorychildren").ParentKeyColumn("ChildID").ChildKeyColumn("ParentID").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildrenCategories).AsBag().Table("parentcategorychildren").ParentKeyColumn("ParentID").ChildKeyColumn("ChildID").Inverse();
```

However, when I try to build the factory, I get the following error:

> The relationship Category.ChildrenCategories to Category.ChildrenCategories has Inverse specified on both sides. Remove Inverse from one side of the relationship.

What I am finding strange is why is it mentioning 'Category.ChildrenCategories' to Category.ChildrenCategories, as opposed to ParentCategories?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**I just created a bounty for this, because it's important enough to me.  Please, I'm not interested in "you can't do this" as an answer.**

Comment: We are having the exact same problem.  An answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it is indeed a bug in FNH, you can always use a traditional xml mapping or the workarounds provided in the answers.

Comment: I've raised [an issue](http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236-fnh/tickets/212-inverse-validation-fails-on-self-referential-relationships) for this. We'll fix it asap.

Comment: The 'bug' in seems to still exists

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is most likely a FNH bug and it is most likely already fixed in the latest FNH [source code](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate). There is no problem when using FNH1.0 and NH2.1. Equivalent HBM mapping works well in FNH1.2 and NH3.1:

```
<bag name="ParentCategories" cascade="all" table="parentcategorychildren">
    <key column="ChildID" />
    <many-to-many column="ParentID" class="Category" />
</bag>

<bag name="ChildrenCategories" inverse="true" table="parentcategorychildren">
    <key column="ParentID" />
    <many-to-many column="ChildID" class="Category" />
</bag>
```

EDIT:
After digging in FNH source code I found a workaround. Let's say, your configuration looks like this:

```
.Mappings(m => {
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Category>();
})
```

The unlucky code can be suppressed by this configuration:

```
.Mappings(m => {
    var persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel();
    persistenceModel.AddMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(Category).Assembly);
    persistenceModel.ValidationEnabled = false; // this makes the trick
    m.UsePersistenceModel(persistenceModel);
})
```

Comment: You can see the check code here https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/ValidationVisitor.cs and it appears to still be in the latest version of FNH.  Is there a way to disable validation on a single map only?

Comment: Yes, it is 1.2 tag. Latest code is on the master branch (https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/ValidationVisitor.cs) but I did not test the version from the master branch so I am not sure if it is already right there (just guess). I don't know how to disable validation for a single MapClass but there are only two validations. The unwanted one and check if Id is mapped. I will live happylly without both of them:).

Comment: I could be misunderstanding what is happening, but it appears the master branch is out of date, it is missing commits that are in 2.1. I don't see a fix to this issue in any branch.

Comment: Master is out of date and should always be considered experimental. The `v1.x` branch is what contains the current release (and fixes going into the next release). The two branches will converge at some point, but it hasn't happened yet. As for this issue, I've created [a ticket](http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236-fnh/tickets/212-inverse-validation-fails-on-self-referential-relationships) for it and we'll get onto it asap.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with Fluent NHibernate 2.1's validation/pairing of relationships.  FNH [pairs up relationships](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/RelationshipPairingVisitor.cs) and then [validates that only one side of the relationship has `.Inverse()` specified](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/ValidationVisitor.cs#L27).  Because both references (parent/child) are to the same class they are both candidate matches when pairing.  In that case, FNH [matches on name similarity](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/RelationshipPairingVisitor.cs#L113). Consequently, they each get paired with themselves rather than each other.  So then placing `.Inverse()` on either one triggers the validation (both sides of the pair are the same relationship which is inverse).

It should be possible to correct this using the `OverrideBiDirectionalManyToManyPairing()` method on the FluentMappingsContainer. In theory, that would allow you to explicitly pair the child and parent relationships.  However, in FNH 2.1 there is a bug, and the override callback is never called. ([The callback value is captured before it can be set by the method](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/PersistenceModel.cs#L43)).

As a work around, you can disable all validation in FNH.  There are [only two validations](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/release-1.2/src/FluentNHibernate/Visitors/ValidationVisitor.cs).  First, that both sides of a relationship don't have `.Inverse()`. Second, that an Id is mapped on each entity.  The cleanest way I have found to disable validation is:

```
.Mappings(m => {
    var persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel() { ValidationEnabled = false };
    m.UsePersistenceModel(persistenceModel)
     .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Category>();
})
```

This approach allows you to disable validation but still use the full expressiveness of the `FluentMappings` configuration.

Comment: Yes, but any other errors would be suppressed as well I assume, which might prove problematic for any future changes to the class mappings without one noticing?

Comment: Well spotted! I (obviously) didn't consider this scenario. I've created [an issue](http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236-fnh/tickets/212-inverse-validation-fails-on-self-referential-relationships) for this and we'll have it sorted asap.

Comment: Karl, yes, disabling validation will disable the two checks I spell out in my answer.  That could be troublesome as more validations are added.  However, Jakub's answer is to disable the same set of validations, just with slightly different code.

Comment: Try `AutoMappings.ValidationEnabled = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seemed to me that it was most likely a bug in FNH, as I tried it directly with NHibernate without using Fluent NH and it worked. However, as I had already setted up a system using FNH I couldn't just revert to not using it.

What I did was I created like a 'class-in-the-middle' myself for the many-to-many relationship, which normally is generated automatically. I created a `ContentPage_ChildLink` page, which linked the `Parents` and `Children` categories. This allowed me to work with FNH and work around the problem :)

Basically this `ContentPage_ChildLink` would have two fields, `ChildID` and `ParentID`.  I could then set the  'Inverse' relationships seperately, without any problem.

The problem with FNH seemed to be when you have a many-to-many relationship, which both sides are the same class, the only case I can think of is a hierarchy structure which allows for multiple parents.

Comment: The situation we have is bank accounts where some accounts are closed and the money is rolled over into other accounts.  This creates a many-to-many from account to account.

Comment: You would need to create another class to link the bank accounts in order to work-around the bug.  You could have a class `AccountLink`, which would have the `MainAccountID` and the `LinkedAccountID`.  The AccountLink would have a one-to-many collection 'LinkedAccounts' which have a One-To-Many relationship `AccountLink` table.  You can traverse the relationship by doing MainAccount.LinkedAccounts[0].LinkedAccount.  Hope it helps !