# How to make many to many relationships in hibernate same table Example

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How to make many to many relationships in hibernate same table Example

I have a model name Product i want to add more Products

want to create extra table where there will two Fields producid and product2 
M-to-Many

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> ManyProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.ImageUrl);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.ManyProduct)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("ProductInProduct");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717973/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-on-same-entity

Comment: use config file of NHibernate and define the relations there

Comment: any other process well 1 product have many product

Answer (score 0):

specify the keycolumns manually

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.ImageUrl);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.ManyProduct)
            .ParentKeyColumn("product1_id")
            .ChildKeyColumn("product2_id")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("ProductInProduct");
    }
}
```